# facebook folly SingletonThreadLocal surprising design

Tags: c++, c++14, folly

folly SingletonThreadLocal class use two "c11 thread_local" and one "ThreadLocal" to support fast access and destruction dependency problems.

But I could not understand the destruction order of "thread_local and ThreadLocal".

```
  FOLLY_EXPORT FOLLY_ALWAYS_INLINE static T& get() {
    if (kIsMobile) {
      return getWrapper();
    }
    static thread_local LocalCache cache;
    return FOLLY_LIKELY(!!cache.cache) ? *cache.cache : getSlow(cache);
  }
  FOLLY_NOINLINE static Wrapper& getSlow(LocalCache& cache) {
    if (threadlocal_detail::StaticMetaBase::dying()) {
      return getWrapper();
    }
    static thread_local LocalLifetime lifetime;
    lifetime.track(cache); // idempotent
    return FOLLY_LIKELY(!!cache.cache) ? *cache.cache : getWrapper();
  }
  struct LocalLifetime {
    ~LocalLifetime() {
      auto& wrapper = getWrapper();
      auto& lifetimes = wrapper.lifetimes[this]; //1. thread wrapper may be destructed.
      for (auto cache : lifetimes) {
        auto const it = wrapper.caches.find(cache);
        if (!--it->second) {
          wrapper.caches.erase(it);
          cache->cache = nullptr;
        }
      }
      wrapper.lifetimes.erase(this);
    }
   ...
   }
  struct Wrapper {
      ~Wrapper() {
      for (auto& kvp : caches) { //cache may be destruct
        kvp.first->cache = nullptr; //2. thread cache maybe destructed.
      }
    }
  }
```

please check the comment 1, 2. the destruction ordered of LocalLifetime LocalCache, and ThreadLocal is undefined, the code may access the destructed memory, it is surprising.

Comment: The destruction order of `cache` and `lifetime` is well-defined (unless a thread calls `getSlow` directly, bypassing `get`).  `cache` is constructed when a thread first reaches its declaration in `get` - which happens before `lifetime` is constructed when the thread in turn reaches its declaration in `getSlow`. Then they are guaranteed to be destroyed in the reverse order of construction.

Comment: In the Wrapper destructor, it modify cache, how to make sure ThreadLocal<Wrapper> destruct before LocalCache?

Comment: I don't see `Wrapper` class used anywhere in the code shown. I can only guess that it's perhaps used in `getWrapper()` somehow, but I can't comment on code I can't see.

Comment: source code:https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/SingletonThreadLocal.h    and it reference a lot of  other source files

Comment: @Mat,  thank you very much, I think i got the anwser. Folly::ThreadLocal use pthread_key_t internally(linux platform),  and C11 thread_local and pthread_key_t destruction order is undefined.  and no matter which order, LocalLifeTime destruct first or pthread_key_t, the code ensure destruct properly.